# Upload ThumbNail

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou com um campo para upload em um formulário *HTML*, gostaria de saber se é possível colocar uma thumb pré-definida, com uploads de imagens sei que da para fazer uma thumb exibindo a imagem que está sendo colocada, mas por exemplo, caso seja upado um arquivo PDF da para colocar um ícone do PDF, de forma que sempre que um arquivo no formato PDF for selecionado apareça um mesmo ícone e o nome do arquivo embaixo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possivel, basta verificares a extenção do ficheiro, existe até uma propriedade `type` para isso. Por exemplo:

```js
const icons = {
  'application/msword': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/blackvariant/button-ui-ms-office-2016/128/Word-2-icon.png',
  'application/pdf': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/alecive/flatwoken/128/Apps-Pdf-icon.png',
  'image/png': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/soft-scraps/128/Image-PNG-icon.png'
}

const input = document.querySelector('input');
const image = document.querySelector('img');
input.addEventListener('change', function() {
  const tipo = this.files[0].type;
  image.src = icons[tipo];
});
```

```html
<input type="file" />
<img src="" style="display: block;"/>
```

Comment: Funcionou bem, mas como posso fazer para o ícone aparecer em vários arquivos, por exemplo estou utilizando upload múltiplo, no caso o ícone só aparece uma vez, se forem 5 arquivos teria que aparecer 5 ícones, sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: @HenriqueBretone nesse caso em  ves de usar somente `this.files[0]` trata como uma array e pega no `.type`  de cada elemento dessa array.